# URLEncode not working for pipe character in java

Tags: java, rest

Getting below exception while encoding pipe character:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at
>   index 292:
>
> at java.net.URI.create(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.(HttpGet.java:69)    at
>   com.versionone.apiclient.V1Connector.setGETMethod(V1Connector.java:349)
>     at com.versionone.apiclient.V1Connector.getData(V1Connector.java:307)
>     at com.versionone.apiclient.Services.retrieve(Services.java:135)    at
>   com.samplev1.v1javasdk.getEpicDetails(v1javasdk.java:120)     at
>   com.samplev1.v1javasdk.main(v1javasdk.java:52)

```
http://www.example.com/uat/rest/Book?sel=Name,Child:Story[Status='StoryStatus:12'|Status='StoryStatus:12'|Status='StoryStatus:1'].Estimate.@Sum
```

If I remove pipe '|' from rest url it works fine, How to encode Pipe character using URLEncoder.

Any help would be appreciated.

Code Sample:

```
private static String EncodeAggregateQuery(String query) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
     String q = URLEncoder.encode(query,"UTF-8");
     return q;

}
```

I'm using above method as:

```
IAttributeDefinition attribute6 = assetType.getAttributeDefinition(EncodeAggregateQuery("Child:Story[Status='StoryStatus:12'|Status='StoryStatus:12'|Status='StoryStatus:1'].Estimate.@Sum"));
```

Comment: Please include the *entire* stack trace, not just the first line of it.  Including the code which generated the exception would also be enormously helpful.

Comment: Can you show where you are calling URLEncoder.encode()

Comment: `"http://www.example.com/uat/rest/Book?sel=" + URLEncoder.encode("...|...")`? Might be some security measure against hacking with pipes.

Comment: Hi Joop, Can you please explain, I couldn't get you

Comment: `URI.create("http://www.example.com/uat/rest/Book?sel=" + URLEncoder.encode("Name,Child:Story[Status='StoryStatus:12'|Status='StoryStatus:12'|Status='StoryStatus:1'].Estimate.@Sum","UTF-8"))` does not throw an exception. Java 8. What is the JRE you are using, and is the stack trace of the exception indeed as you listed?

Comment: It works when i remove pipe character from string

Answer (score 0):

If your URL encoding scheme doesn't appear to work, you could always use the hex character code.  If you review an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), you will see that the pipe char has the hex code of 7C. So you could simply replace pipes with %7C before you submit your URL.